# Accessing private fields without bytecode-verificator

Tags: java, security, compiler-construction, verification

The example is taken from the O'Reilly Java Security book.

There are two classes
Card.java

```
public class Card {
    public int num = 123234;
}
```

and 
Test.java

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Card card = new Card();
        System.out.println("Your card - " + card.num);
    }
}
```

I compile both classes using Java **1.2**. Then I change the modifier of the `num` field to private and recompile only the `Card` class.

Starting the Test (java Test) class produces the following output.

> Your card - 123234.

So it worked even without switching off the bytecode verifier (Though the author says that had we not the bytecode verifier, it would work).

Now I do the same using Java **1.6**.
Starting the Test class produces `IllegalAccessError`, even if I start it with `-noverify`.

The questions are:

1) Does it have anything to do with bytecode verifier. If it does not, who produced the error.

2) Was it a bug in previous versions of Java then?

Comment: You know that 1.2 was released in 1998, right?

Comment: So? :) How does it contradict with my question :)

Comment: I mean they've definitely were working on bytecode security since 1.2 and who cares if 1.2 have some bugs in it nowadays?

Comment: They sure have. That's exactly the question I asked. If it's a bug, and what does it have to do with bytecode verifier

Comment: **I think** this was introduced for early implementations of inner/nested classes. In any case, if a class can be injected into a runtime package (note: needs to be same class loader for it to be the same package even if the name is the same) then there is going to be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it was an old verifier bug.  It looks like it was this one:

http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4007892

It is not clear from the (public) bug history exactly when it was fixed, but I suspect that it was fixed a long time ago.

---

> If it's a bug, and what does it have to do with bytecode verifier

The bytecode verifier *should* check that a class doesn't attempt to reference private fields of another class.  This check is supposed to happen when the classes are loaded by the JVM.

Comment: Why didn't switching the verifier off in 1.6 help access the field then?

Comment: The bug is closed as a duplicate, apparently of http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4066506 . Which just refers to locally-loaded classes and was apparently fixed in a 1.2 beta after 1.2 fcs was released...

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline - You can see that, but mere mortals can't :-)

Comment: I got that this is a normal behavior if you do not load classes from network (Which is my case). But why do I get this exception with switched off verifier? Seems that exception not from the verifier.

Comment: @AverageJoe - Not necessarily.  It could be that `-noverify` only turns part of the verifier off ... or that it is being silently ignored.  Note that `-noverify` isn't listed in the `java` manual page.